# VBS How to determine if a program is running

Tags: vbscript, solidworks

I need a way to determine if a process with a visible window is open, using VBScript.

For example, when I close the *SolidWorks* window, the `SolidWorks.exe` process remains running.

How can I find out which is which? Any suggestions?

Comment: Define what *you* mean by "a program". Because from the view of the operating system there are only processes.

Comment: By running i mean that it is available to maximize without having to run an .exe file first. But solidworks has the process sldworks.exe running after the first time it is openen after a boot. Closing solidworks as you close any other program does not stop the process sldworks.exe, so when my VBS searches to see if solidworks is open, it gets a positive, but when a command is sent to solid, the program bugs because it is not really open..?

Comment: So you need to determine if a program has a *visible* window? I don't think that will be possible with VBScript. You could do it with a C or .NET program by calling the [Windows API function `IsWindowVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I have a feeling that this answer is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Ye, it might be the case. However, it is a rather large program made in VBScript, for easing the process for design engineers. The problem is that right now it is impossible for me to determine whether the program is running or not because as you say, the visible window has to be there, to run the shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the command line program `tasklist.exe` to find out if the right window is open.

If you run `tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq sldworks.exe"` and find a difference between the process you are interested in and the other one, this might work.

Assuming there is a specific window title you can look for:

```
Dim pid = GetProcessId("sldworks.exe", "That window title")
If pid > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Yay we found it"
End If
```

where `GetProcessId()` is this

```
Function GetProcessId(imageName, windowTitle)
    Dim currentUser, command, output, tasklist, tasks, i, cols

    currentUser = CreateObject("Wscript.Network").UserName

    command = "tasklist /V /FO csv"
    command = command & " /FI ""USERNAME eq " + currentUser + """"
    command = command & " /FI ""IMAGENAME eq " + imageName + """"
    command = command & " /FI ""WINDOWTITLE eq " + windowTitle + """"
    command = command & " /FI ""SESSIONNAME eq Console"""
    ' add more or different filters, see tasklist /?

    output = Trim(Shell(command))
    tasklist = Split(output, vbNewLine)

    ' starting at 1 skips first line (it contains the column headings only)
    For i = 1 To UBound(tasklist) - 1
        cols = Split(tasklist(i), """,""")
        ' a line is expected to have 9 columns (0-8)
        If UBound(cols) = 8 Then
            GetProcessId = Trim(cols(1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function Shell(cmd)
    Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll()
End Function
```

You don't have to return the PID, you could also return `True`/`False` or any other information `tasklist` provides. For reference, the `tasklist` column indexes are:

- 0: "Image Name"
- 1: "PID",
- 2: "Session Name"
- 3: "Session#"
- 4: "Mem Usage",
- 5: "Status"
- 6: "User Name"
- 7: "CPU Time"
- 8: "Window Title"

More advanced interaction with processes is available through the WMI. Plenty of examples how to use that in VBScript are all over the Internet. Search for `Win32_Process`.